# Algorithm for representing a polynomial as a composition of lower degree polynomials

Tags: algorithms, polynomials

Let $q$ be a large prime and $e$ an integer such that $GCD(e,q-1)=1$. Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $e^n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_q$ such that there exists a progression of polynomials (the "composition")

- $p_i(x) = a_i(p_{i-1}(x))^e+b_i$, $a_i, b_i \ne 0$ with
- $p_0(x) = x$ and
- $p(x) = p_n(x)$

Given $q$ and $p(x)$, how do I find any such composition?

**Note:** The condition $GCD(e,q-1)$ implies that each $p_i(x)$ is a permutation over $\mathbb Z_q$. I ask because I am trying to find an efficient algorithm for finding the roots of $p(x)-c$ for any $c$. It is possible my approach is inadequate, but unfortunately it means I am not helped by answers that presuppose that I am already able to find such roots. I am not, that's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Why?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Did you want the degree to be $e^n$ (rather than $ne$)?  Also, do you really want $e$ to be coprime to $q-1$, or should it be coprime to $q$?

Comment: There's no loss in requiring $a_i=1$ for $i<n$, since you can replace $p_2(x)$ and $p_1(x)$ by $p_2(xa_1)$ and $p_1(x)/a_1$ in order to make $p_1$ be monic, and then you can do the same thing to make $p_2,p_3,...,p_{n-1}$ be monic.  So you might as well assume that $p(x)$ is monic and every $a_i=1$.

Comment: @MichaelZieve: You are correct that the degree will be $e^n$, but wrong about $GCD(e,q-1) = 1$. One point is to use the algorithm as a starting point for finding an algorithm for evaluating $p^{-1}(y)$, which has the same time complexity as evaluating $p(x)$ using the algorithm that is implicit in my question, i.e. no worse than $O(nlog(q)^2))$.

Comment: Doesn't Knuth give an algorithm for this in *The Art of Computer Programming* vol 2?

Comment: @ZsbánAmbrus: Please correct me if I am wrong, but AFAIK, no. There is no generic algorithm for finding roots of polynomials of degree $n > 5$, and the the algorithm for finding $r(x)$ such that $r(x)q(x) \equiv 1 (mod p(x))$ is obviously different from finding $r(x)$ such that $r(p(x)) = x$. That is, the multiplicative inverse in a polynomial ring, is not the same as the functional inverse of the same polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my comment, I will assume that $p(x)$ and all $p_i(x)$ are monic.  I will also assume that $\gcd(e,q)=1$.  All of these hypotheses can be removed easily.  To make the problem nontrivial, assume that $e>1$.  The only issue is to determine $b_n$; if that can be done, then $p_{n-1}(x)$ is the unique monic $e$-th root of $p(x)-b_n$, and one can similarly determine $b_{n-1},p_{n-2},b_{n-2},...,p_1$.  One way to determine $b_n$ is to compute the resultant with respect to $y$ of $p'(y)$ and $p(y)-x$. This resultant will be a polynomial in $x$ of degree $2e^n-2$ which has $b_n$ as a root of multiplicity at least $e^n-e^{n-1}$, so $b_n$ can be read off from the resultant.

Another approach is to compute the coefficients of $x^{-1},x^{-2},...,x^{-e^{n-1}}$ in the expansion of the $e$-th root of $p(x)/x^{e^n}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_q[[1/x]]$ (made to be unique by requiring constant term $1$).  If $r(x)$ is the unique monic polynomial of degree $e^{n-1}$ such that 
$$
\frac{p(x)}{x^{e^n}} - \Bigl(\frac{r(x)}{x^{e^{n-1}}}\Bigr)^e$$ is in $x^{-e^{n-1}-1}\mathbb{Z}_q[[1/x]]$, then $r(x)$ is also the unique monic polynomial of degree $e^{n-1}$ such that $p(x)-r(x)^e$ has degree less than $e^n-e^{n-1}$. Since $p(x)-p_{n-1}(x)^e$ is constant we must have $p_{n-1}(x)=r(x)$, and then $b_n=p(x)-r(x)^e$ can be determined.